# GlassMapper - Boolean method not found HasValue

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

just installed glass mapper on a new Sitecore 8.1 solution and as soon as I loaded up the site I keep getting the following error - more details in screenshot.

Any thoughts?

*Method not found: 'Boolean Glass.Mapper.ExtensionMethods.HasValue(System.String)'.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you refferenced a wrong Glass.Mapper.dll from a old version of GlassMapper

Can you check if you have this method

```
  /// <summary>
/// Indicates whether the specified string has a value, i.e. Not null or empty
/// 
/// </summary>
public static bool HasValue(this string target)
{
  return !ExtensionMethods.IsNullOrEmpty(target);
}
```

inside class Glass.Mapper.ExtensionMethods

I checked on GlassMapper vers 4.0.5

Comment: thanks for that - i had it all installed through the Nuget Package manager thinking it's the latest version but it wasn't!